# Java is reading old input files, not new ones

Tags: java

I have some java code which reads text files, adds the contents to a vector and then prints these points to screen using a graph windower.

I have three pointdata.txt files, pointdata1.txt, pointdata2.txt and pointdata3.txt.

The problem i am having is that, even when i change the input file in my driver to pointdata1 or pointdata2, it still runs for pointdata3. I have ensured that there are no occurences of pointdata3 anywhere else in the code. It only appears twice, but i have made sure it is the same. 
I have checked the files themselves, they are different. Checked and checked and checked the pathnames, they are different!

Even when i comment out every `System.out.println()` in the entire code, it still prints everything!

It is asif the code is no longer refereing the the text files, or even running, eclipse just keeps printing what was previously added to the viewport?

Here is the code from my driver:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PointDriver {
private PointField pointfield;

    // testing
    public void doAllTests() throws Exception{
        this.test1();
        this.test2();
    }

    // Display all points in the file
    public void test1() throws Exception{

        SimpleIO sIO = new SimpleIO();

        System.out.println("Contents of Point File: "); 
        sIO.displayFile("pointdata1.txt");
        //sIO.displayFile("pointdata2.txt");
        //sIO.displayFile("pointdata3.txt");        
        System.out.println();   

    }

// Load points from a file into a vector and echo them back to the screen 
// This uses the StringTokenizer to split the lines into two Strings, then
// uses the Point class to assign the two Strings to x,y double variables 
// which form Points.  Within the same loop, the points are also displayed
// in a window using the Graph Window class. Maximum x and y values are used  
// to determine the dimensions of the GraphWindow, adding 10 units to each 
// value to provide a border.
    public void test2() throws Exception{

        System.out.println("Contents of Point File: ");
        System.out.println();   
        System.out.println("Points are Displayed in a Graph Window");
        System.out.println();   

        Vector lines;
        lines = pointfield.getlines("pointdata1.txt");
        //lines = pointfield.getlines("pointdata2.txt");
        //lines = pointfield.getlines("pointdata3.txt");            

        Iterator IT;
        IT = lines.iterator();      

        Vector v;
        v = new Vector();

        double maxX, maxY;          

        PointField pointfield;
        pointfield = new PointField();

        GraphWindow gw;
        gw = new GraphWindow();

        while (IT.hasNext()) {

            StringTokenizer st;

            String ID = (String)IT.next();
            st = new StringTokenizer(ID);

            double x = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            double y = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());

            Point p;
            p = new Point(x,y);

            v.addElement(p);

            int i = v.size();
            System.out.println("Point ID: " +i+ " X: "+x+", Y: "+y);    

            gw.plotPoint(x, y);                 
        }

        this.pointfield = new PointField(v);
        maxX = this.pointfield.findMaxXPoint();
        maxY = this.pointfield.findMaxYPoint();

        int width = (int)maxX + 10;
        int height = (int)maxY + 10;

        gw.setMap(width, height);       
    }

    // Short main method to kick of all tests sequence in doAllTests method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PointFieldDriver pfd;
        pfd = new PointFieldDriver();
        pfd.doAllTests();
    }
}
```

Comment: We'd have to see your code to know exactly. I suggest that you run a debugger on it. Also, is your project compiling? You could try building to a JAR file and seeing what happens if you run that.

Comment: would adding the code from my driver be helpful?

Comment: Everything you can give us that is relevant is helpful.

Comment: when i run debugger it still runs the same output as before..

Comment: ive added the code from my driver class

Comment: Obviously you are running the old code not the new code.

Comment: but i dont have any old code! how would i know if i was running an old version?

Comment: ive saved it since changing to pointdata1.txt if thats what you mean?

Comment: Java classes are compiled to bytecode; specifically, `*.java` files are compiled into `*.class` files, and those `*.class` files are what are actually run. So if something goes wrong during compilation, then you'll still be running your old `*.class` files, even though you've changed the `*.java` files. Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: ahhah! how would i know if it is running my old .class files.. also why would it do that.. aand.. how can i change it?

Comment: @alice you would know if you thought you had changed it but still got the old behaviour instead of the expected new behaviour, as appears to be the case here. Do a clean build.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Eclipse is running an old version of your class file. I'm gathering this as you said that you commented out the printlns, but the output is still displaying.

A few things to check:

- In the menu, make sure that **Project** > **Build Automatically** is set. If that isn't set, set it, and your problem should be solved.
- See whether the timestamp on your class file is changing when you change the source. If it isn't, then Eclipse isn't recompiling it for some reason. You can find the class file probably under the bin folder (if you are using the Eclipse project defaults).
- If you find the timestamp is old, try removing the bin folder from outside of Eclipse. Next, right-click on the project and select refresh. Finally, select **Project** > **Clean**. This should cause the code to be recompiled into a new class file.

Comment: Yes, 8 times out of 10 your problem will be Eclipse. Upgrade to IDEA and make your life easier.

Comment: ok.. so i tried everything you said, and it was running old .CLASS files, so i cleaned the bin - and now it is making new ones everytime i run the code.. but it still is running the old code! How is this even possible??

Comment: if i try and open the .CLASS files it has made in notepad they are full of wingdings - or are they meant to be like this?

Comment: Weird. Might want to try creating a new project with a "hello world" class and see whether you can get change > compile > run round trip working, If so, moving the code over to the new working project might be your best bet.

Comment: I'm a Netbeans user.  I sometimes get this same problem.  I have to manually delete the cache (which is somewhere like $user/.Netbeans/var/cache).  There might be something similar with Eclipse.  The cache is something completely different from the bin/ (or build/) directory.